# Unhandled Runtime Error Error: missing argument: passed to contract (count=0, expectedCount=1, code=MISSING_ARGUMENT, version=contracts/5.5.0)

Tags: web3js, nft, hardhat, hardhat-deploy, smart-contract

basically, I am building a nft marketplace and whenever I want to create a nft and publish it I keep getting this error, it definitely has something to do with my smart contract, deploy.js or my front-end code.

here is my smart contract code for my nftmarketplace.sol:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721URIStorage.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";

import "hardhat/console.sol";

contract NFTMarketplace is ERC721URIStorage {
    using Counters for Counters.Counter;
    Counters.Counter private _tokenIds;
    Counters.Counter private _itemsSold;

    uint256 listingPrice = 0.025 ether;
    address payable owner;

    mapping(uint256 => MarketItem) private idToMarketItem;

    struct MarketItem {
      uint256 tokenId;
      address payable seller;
      address payable owner;
      uint256 price;
      bool sold;
    }

    event MarketItemCreated (
      uint256 indexed tokenId,
      address seller,
      address owner,
      uint256 price,
      bool sold
    );

    constructor() ERC721("Metaverse Tokens", "METT") {
      owner = payable(msg.sender);
    }

    /* Updates the listing price of the contract */
    function updateListingPrice(uint _listingPrice) public payable {
      require(owner == msg.sender, "Only marketplace owner can update listing price.");
      listingPrice = _listingPrice;
    }

    /* Returns the listing price of the contract */
    // function getListingPrice() public view returns (uint256) {
    //   return listingPrice;
    // }

    function getListingPrice(uint256 tokenId) public view returns (uint256) {
        return listingPrice;
    }

    /* Mints a token and lists it in the marketplace */
    function createToken(string memory tokenURI, uint256 price) public payable returns (uint) {
      _tokenIds.increment();
      uint256 newTokenId = _tokenIds.current();

      _mint(msg.sender, newTokenId);
      _setTokenURI(newTokenId, tokenURI);
      createMarketItem(newTokenId, price);
      return newTokenId;
    }

    function createMarketItem(
      uint256 tokenId,
      uint256 price
    ) private {
      require(price > 0, "Price must be at least 1 wei");
      require(msg.value == listingPrice, "Price must be equal to listing price");

      idToMarketItem[tokenId] =  MarketItem(
        tokenId,
        payable(msg.sender),
        payable(address(this)),
        price,
        false
      );

      _transfer(msg.sender, address(this), tokenId);
      emit MarketItemCreated(
        tokenId,
        msg.sender,
        address(this),
        price,
        false
      );
    }

    /* allows someone to resell a token they have purchased */
    function resellToken(uint256 tokenId, uint256 price) public payable {
      require(idToMarketItem[tokenId].owner == msg.sender, "Only item owner can perform this operation");
      require(msg.value == listingPrice, "Price must be equal to listing price");
      idToMarketItem[tokenId].sold = false;
      idToMarketItem[tokenId].price = price;
      idToMarketItem[tokenId].seller = payable(msg.sender);
      idToMarketItem[tokenId].owner = payable(address(this));
      _itemsSold.decrement();

      _transfer(msg.sender, address(this), tokenId);
    }

    /* Creates the sale of a marketplace item */
    /* Transfers ownership of the item, as well as funds between parties */
    function createMarketSale(
      uint256 tokenId
      ) public payable {
      uint price = idToMarketItem[tokenId].price;
      address seller = idToMarketItem[tokenId].seller;
      require(msg.value == price, "Please submit the asking price in order to complete the purchase");
      idToMarketItem[tokenId].owner = payable(msg.sender);
      idToMarketItem[tokenId].sold = true;
      idToMarketItem[tokenId].seller = payable(address(0));
      _itemsSold.increment();
      _transfer(address(this), msg.sender, tokenId);
      payable(owner).transfer(listingPrice);
      payable(seller).transfer(msg.value);
    }

    /* Returns all unsold market items */
    function fetchMarketItems() public view returns (MarketItem[] memory) {
      uint itemCount = _tokenIds.current();
      uint unsoldItemCount = _tokenIds.current() - _itemsSold.current();
      uint currentIndex = 0;

      MarketItem[] memory items = new MarketItem[](unsoldItemCount);
      for (uint i = 0; i < itemCount; i++) {
        if (idToMarketItem[i + 1].owner == address(this)) {
          uint currentId = i + 1;
          MarketItem storage currentItem = idToMarketItem[currentId];
          items[currentIndex] = currentItem;
          currentIndex += 1;
        }
      }
      return items;
    }

    /* Returns only items that a user has purchased */
    function fetchMyNFTs() public view returns (MarketItem[] memory) {
      uint totalItemCount = _tokenIds.current();
      uint itemCount = 0;
      uint currentIndex = 0;

      for (uint i = 0; i < totalItemCount; i++) {
        if (idToMarketItem[i + 1].owner == msg.sender) {
          itemCount += 1;
        }
      }

      MarketItem[] memory items = new MarketItem[](itemCount);
      for (uint i = 0; i < totalItemCount; i++) {
        if (idToMarketItem[i + 1].owner == msg.sender) {
          uint currentId = i + 1;
          MarketItem storage currentItem = idToMarketItem[currentId];
          items[currentIndex] = currentItem;
          currentIndex += 1;
        }
      }
      return items;
    }

    /* Returns only items a user has listed */
    function fetchItemsListed() public view returns (MarketItem[] memory) {
      uint totalItemCount = _tokenIds.current();
      uint itemCount = 0;
      uint currentIndex = 0;

      for (uint i = 0; i < totalItemCount; i++) {
        if (idToMarketItem[i + 1].seller == msg.sender) {
          itemCount += 1;
        }
      }

      MarketItem[] memory items = new MarketItem[](itemCount);
      for (uint i = 0; i < totalItemCount; i++) {
        if (idToMarketItem[i + 1].seller == msg.sender) {
          uint currentId = i + 1;
          MarketItem storage currentItem = idToMarketItem[currentId];
          items[currentIndex] = currentItem;
          currentIndex += 1;
        }
      }
      return items;
    }
}
```

here is the other smart contract for my nft itself:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity >=0.6.0 <0.9.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721URIStorage.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol";

contract NFT is ERC721URIStorage {
    using Counters for Counters.Counter;    
    Counters.Counter private _tokenIds;
    address contractAddress;

    constructor(address marketplaceAddress) ERC721("Metaverse Tokens", "MET") {
        contractAddress = marketplaceAddress;
    }

    function createToken(string memory tokenURI) public returns (uint) {
        _tokenIds.increment();
        uint256 newItemID = _tokenIds.current();

        _mint(msg.sender, newItemID);
        _setTokenURI(newItemID, tokenURI);
        setApprovalForAll(contractAddress, true);
        return newItemID;
    }
}
```

here is the code for my deploy.js:

```
const hre = require("hardhat");
const fs = require("fs");

async function main() {
  const NFTMarketplace = await hre.ethers.getContractFactory("NFTMarketplace");
  const nftMarketplace = await NFTMarketplace.deploy();
  await nftMarketplace.deployed();
  console.log("nftMarketplace deployed to:", nftMarketplace.address);

  const NFT = await hre.ethers.getContractFactory("NFT");
  const nft = await NFT.deploy(nftMarketplace);
  await nft.deployed();
  console.log("nft deployed to: ", nft.address);

  fs.writeFileSync(
    "./config.js",
    `export const marketplaceAddress = ${nftMarketplace.address}`
  );
}

main()
  .then(() => process.exit(0))
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
    process.exit(1);
  });
```

and finally, here is my front-end code:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { ethers } from "ethers";
import { create as ipfsHttpClient } from "ipfs-http-client";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import Web3Modal from "web3modal";

const client = ipfsHttpClient("https://ipfs.infura.io:5001/api/v0");

import { marketplaceAddress } from "../config";

import NFTMarketplace from "../artifacts/contracts/NFTMarketplace.sol/NFTMarketplace.json";

export default function CreateItem() {
  const [fileUrl, setFileUrl] = useState(null);
  const [formInput, updateFormInput] = useState({
    price: "",
    name: "",
    description: "",
  });
  const router = useRouter();

  async function onChange(e) {
    const file = e.target.files[0];
    try {
      const added = await client.add(file, {
        progress: (prog) => console.log(`received: ${prog}`),
      });
      const url = `https://ipfs.infura.io/ipfs/${added.path}`;
      setFileUrl(url);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Error uploading file: ", error);
    }
  }
  async function uploadToIPFS() {
    const { name, description, price } = formInput;
    if (!name || !description || !price || !fileUrl) return;
    /* first, upload to IPFS */
    const data = JSON.stringify({
      name,
      description,
      image: fileUrl,
    });
    try {
      const added = await client.add(data);
      const url = `https://ipfs.infura.io/ipfs/${added.path}`;
      /* after file is uploaded to IPFS, return the URL to use it in the transaction */
      return url;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Error uploading file: ", error);
    }
  }

  async function listNFTForSale() {
    const url = await uploadToIPFS();
    const web3Modal = new Web3Modal();
    const connection = await web3Modal.connect();
    const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(connection);
    const signer = provider.getSigner();

    /* next, create the item */
    const price = ethers.utils.parseUnits(formInput.price, "ether");
    let contract = new ethers.Contract(
      marketplaceAddress,
      NFTMarketplace.abi,
      signer
    );
    let listingPrice = await contract.getListingPrice();
    listingPrice = listingPrice.toString();
    let transaction = await contract.createToken(url, price, {
      value: listingPrice,
    });
    await transaction.wait();

    router.push("/");
  }

  return (
    <div className="flex justify-center">
      <div className="w-1/2 flex flex-col pb-12">
        <input
          placeholder="Asset Name"
          className="mt-8 border rounded p-4"
          onChange={(e) =>
            updateFormInput({ ...formInput, name: e.target.value })
          }
        />
        <textarea
          placeholder="Asset Description"
          className="mt-2 border rounded p-4"
          onChange={(e) =>
            updateFormInput({ ...formInput, description: e.target.value })
          }
        />
        <input
          placeholder="Asset Price in Eth"
          className="mt-2 border rounded p-4"
          onChange={(e) =>
            updateFormInput({ ...formInput, price: e.target.value })
          }
        />
        <input type="file" name="Asset" className="my-4" onChange={onChange} />{" "}
        {fileUrl && (
          <image className="xyz" width="350" src={fileUrl} />
        )}
        <button onClick={listNFTForSale} className="Create-nft-button">
          Create NFT
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This error refers to your deployment process

Within your **deploy.js file**, at this line:   `const nft = await NFT.deploy(nftMarketplace),` replace `nftMarketplace` with `nftMarketplace.address`, and it should be fine.

Like `const nft = await NFT.deploy(nftMarketplace.address)`

Remember that when you deploy a contract within your **deploy.js** file by `deploy()` & `deployed()` commands, the result will be an object with diverse properties rather than an address. However, there is a `.address` **property** in that object that represents the **address of the deployed contract**.

Ultimately, since your NFT contract's constructor function **demands an address**, you must provide an address, not an object.

Try console.log the contracts you deploy in deploy.js to get used to their properties!

Good luck

Comment: I still get the same error after adding nftmarketplace.address, nothing has changed.

Comment: If you want, you can give me access to your code so I can reproduce the error and help you find the origin

Comment: But for sure, one of the errors is the argument you pass to the await NFT.deploy( )

Comment: here is my github repo

Comment: https://github.com/eyad-ahmed-18/NFTMarketplace/tree/main

Comment: Please specify when you get this error. While trying to mint nfts from your user interface the error is shown on your console? Please elaborate on your error

Comment: I fixed this error, but whenever I want to create a new NFT on the create-nft.js, it will show an error saying  Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: call revert exception (method="getListingPrice()", errorArgs=null, errorName=null, errorSignature=null, reason=null, code=CALL_EXCEPTION, version=abi/5.5.0).